# React js nested axios call

Tags: reactjs, axios

How can i make nested **axios** call? I need to pass the result of first axios call as parameter to second **axios**

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can chain just like a normal promise. Fire off the next request in the `.then` of the first request and then return that promise so you'll have a `.then` for you second request.

```
axios.get(...)
  .then((response) => {
    return axios.get(...); // using response.data
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Response', response);
  });
```

Comment: what happens if the return request fails, how do you catch that specific one?

Comment: @Omar You can return a `catch` with the promise: `return axios.get(...).catch(...)`

Comment: I am calling 3 APIs continuously, I used the above code and it is working but the thing is inside the second API I am printing something but it is not able to print but it is printing in logs. How does it solve?

Comment: @Omar This is not working in my case, any other solution for the same?